# Why I can run less, grep and find in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, grep, less-unix

A friend told me that Windows PowerShell doesn't have these Unix-style commands. Well, I tried and saw that I can in fact run these.

Now I'm wondering why is that. Could it be because I have installed NodeJs on this Windows machine?

If they are not by default usable in Windows PowerShell, is there a way to find out what exactly has brought them into use in this Windows installation?

Running Windows 8.1.

---

For those that are interested, based on the chosen answer, I found out that installing Git on this machine has brought those commands to use:

```
PS C:\Users\myusername> where.exe grep
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\grep.exe

PS C:\Users\myusername> where.exe less
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\less.exe
```

Comment: `find` in Windows is `find.exe` which is a tool similar to `grep` in Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
where.exe find
where.exe less
where.exe grep
```

They'll return the path to the exe file if those tools exist on your PC. You can always run [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) because there's `find.exe`, although it's not Unix `find` but a tool for searching text. `less` and `grep` won't be available by default but if you have Cygwin, MSYS or Gnu32 installed then they'll be ready in path. Git on Windows runs on MSYS so unsurprisingly you can run `less`, `grep` or other Unix tools

Note that you need to use `where.exe command` instead of only `where command` like on cmd.exe because `where` on powershell has a different meaning

Comment: Thanks. Git installation brought those commands :) I'll update the question and refer to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you wonder why you can see them, you can run the `Get-Command` command, which will tell you where the files are being called from (also a great tool to find the underlying VBS scripts which get called when you run commands from time to time)

For instance, the `LS` command works in PowerShell, but it isn't actually the same binary used in Bash.

```
_>Get-Command ls

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

We can see here that in this case, running `LS` is actually a PowerShell alias which calls the Cmdlet (that is to say, the native PowerShell command) of `Get-ChildItem`.

If you run this on the other commands you can determine why you see them.  Maybe you install cygwin at some point, or installed Python / Ruby (some installers package Bash binaries).